# Sagepay integration without mcrypt

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt

I am looking to integrate with Sagepay/Opayo Form using their guidance here:
https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/25041/download-document/FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_270815.pdf?token=Cfj49hcaD4kpE0zk7179ZLOaQx2RH_3oatPOrAV6MyM

Sagepay have now stopped supporting SDKs which means I've had to find a 2013 utility set from here:
https://github.com/ammaar23/sagepay-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/classes/util.php

I am trying to migrate away from mcrypt towards `openssl_encrypt` but cannot seem to replicate the desired result.

There are 2 functions in play:

```
static protected function addPKCS5Padding($input)
{
$blockSize = 16;
$padd = "";

// Pad input to an even block size boundary.
$length = $blockSize - (strlen($input) % $blockSize);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++)
{
$padd .= chr($length);
}

return $input . $padd;
}

static public function encryptAes($string, $key)
{
// AES encryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding then HEX encoding.
// Add PKCS5 padding to the text to be encypted.
$string = self::addPKCS5Padding($string);

// AH updated as mcrypt is now deprecated! 2020
$cipher = 'AES-128-CBC';
$ivsize = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivsize);

$crypt = openssl_encrypt($string,$cipher,$key,0,$iv);

// Perform hex encoding and return.
return "@" . strtoupper(bin2hex($crypt));
}
```

You can see my attempts to implement openssl_encrypt but it isn't working. The key is `55a51621a6648525` and the input string is `VendorTxCode=TxCode-1310917599-223087284&Amount=36.95&Currency=GBP&Description=description&CustomerName=Fname Surname&CustomerEMail=customer@example.com&BillingSurname=Surname&BillingFirstnames=Fname&BillingAddress1=BillAddress Line 1&BillingCity=BillCity&BillingPostCode=W1A 1BL&BillingCountry=GB&BillingPhone=447933000000&DeliveryFirstnames=Fname&DeliverySurname=Surname&DeliveryAddress1=BillAddress Line 1&DeliveryCity=BillCity&DeliveryPostCode=W1A 1BL&DeliveryCountry=GB&DeliveryPhone=447933000000&SuccessURL=https://example.com/success&FailureURL=https://example.com/failure`

**and the output result is:**

`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`

How can I create the desired output from my input code because the output I generate starts with: `403444324634333730363535313636373136413432363737353332363133303644373736`

Comment: Due to the random IV, even with identical plaintext and key a different ciphertext is generated with each encryption.

Comment: Ah! ok - I'm not sure how their system will cope with that so I'll give it a try as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `openssl_encrypt` applies PKCS7 padding by default, so the `addPKCS5Padding` method is no longer needed.
- In the `mcrypt_encrypt` code iv = key is used, so you must not generate a random IV for code equivalence.
- In `openssl_encrypt` the flag `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` must be applied as 4th parameter, otherwise the data will be returned Base64 encoded.

With these changes, the `openssl_encrypt` code produces the same result as the `mcrypt_encrypt` code:

```
<?php
function encryptAes($string, $key)
{
    //$string = self::addPKCS5Padding($string);                                     // don't pad explicitly
 
    $cipher = 'AES-128-CBC';                                                        
    //$ivsize = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    //$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivsize);                                   // mcrypt_encrypt code: iv = key

    $crypt = openssl_encrypt($string,$cipher,$key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$key);           // use raw data

    return "@" . strtoupper(bin2hex($crypt));
}

$plain = "VendorTxCode=TxCode-1310917599-223087284&Amount=36.95&Currency=GBP&Description=description&CustomerName=Fname Surname&CustomerEMail=customer@example.com&BillingSurname=Surname&BillingFirstnames=Fname&BillingAddress1=BillAddress Line 1&BillingCity=BillCity&BillingPostCode=W1A 1BL&BillingCountry=GB&BillingPhone=447933000000&DeliveryFirstnames=Fname&DeliverySurname=Surname&DeliveryAddress1=BillAddress Line 1&DeliveryCity=BillCity&DeliveryPostCode=W1A 1BL&DeliveryCountry=GB&DeliveryPhone=447933000000&SuccessURL=https://example.com/success&FailureURL=https://example.com/failure";
$key = "55a51621a6648525";
print(encryptAes($plain, $key));
?>
```

For the choice iv = key note also the answers to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/problems-with-using-aes-key-as-iv-in-cbc-mode).

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting a 500 error from Sagepay saying "The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.". I'm not sure if that is a problem my end or theirs and I've emailed them but once I confirm this is working I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: The code I posted generates the same ciphertext on my machine as the corresponding method in the [linked code](https://github.com/ammaar23/sagepay-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/classes/util.php) (assuming the same key and plaintext). Have you verified if this is also the case in your environment? If so, you may need to make adjustments beyond simply replacing mcrypt with openssl (although unfortunately I don't know which).

Answer (score 0):

@Topaco answered beautifully. Here is an additional bit, ( not related to the question ), while doing Sagepay integration you will need the decrypt function too for verifying payment/callback. Here is the function you can use.

```
    function decrypytAES($string, $key) {
        $cipher = 'AES-128-CBC';
        $strIn = hex2bin(substr($strIn, 1));
        return openssl_decrypt($strIn, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $key);
    }
```